# ASP.NET 5 Beta 8 Hosting error: HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a new ASP.NET 5 Beta 8 project using simply the default template.

When I publish the project and host it on a server using IIS 8.5 I get the error:

```
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.
```

1. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5;
2. I have the application running on a No Managed code application pool
3. I have HttpPlataformHandler 1.2 installed.

What might be wrong?

Comment: can you try with rc1 version?

Comment: I just changed all template dependencies from 1.0.0-beta8 to 1.0.0-*. With that some where updated to RC1 (Diagnostics, Kestrel, StaticFiles, Razor, and JSon) ... The others, including MVC stayed at Beta8 and it seems there is not RC1 release (I tried it manually). Nevertheless I was able to publish but when I moved it to the server I got the same error again: HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway ... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at the issue with the new [hosting model](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364)

Comment: I have the same problem... did you find a solution?